# Open reply form with addition to and cc fields in Outlook Web Add-in

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to add extra recepients inaddition to the existing ones in reply mail invoked by plugin.

My code :

```js
Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyAllForm(
        {
            'htmlBody' : emailBodyHtml,
            'normalizedSubject' : subject,
            'to' : to,
            'cc' : cc,
            'callback' : function(asyncResult)
            {
                console.log('reply mail with asyncResult.value ==> ' + asyncResult);
            }
        });
```

Unfortunately it is not setting `to` and `cc` emails which are added by me. Not even throwing any error. It is taking default mails of parent mail. How could I make it to open reply mail with addition emails?

Comment: @SandunTharaka i am giving an array of email Ids.

Comment: I think its not yet possible. See their document to displayReplyAllForm (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item?product=outlook&version=v1.5 ) parameters list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `to` and `cc` properties are not currently supported by [displayReplyForm](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item#displayreplyformformdata) or [displayReplyAllForm](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item#displayreplyallformformdata) methods at this time.

I would recommended adding this request to the [Office UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) so that it can be considered by the Outlook team going forward.

Comment: opened request : https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/30943603-need-api-support-to-add-to-and-cc-people-in-displa